# How to reduce the list of doubles to string?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm new to functional methods like reduce and fold in java 8 and Kotlin. I want to reduce -

```
List<List<List<Double>>> boundingPolygon = [[[-125.48845080566404,47.94508483691371],[-124.96110705566404,42.309040799653665],[-117.13884143066404,45.04173793121063],[-118.36931018066404,48.93624688577435],[-125.48845080566404,47.94508483691371]]];
```

to single string that represents one String concatenated by coordinates -

```
"-118.359053 33.931562,-118.372443 33.946939,-118.369053 33.951562,-118.337612 33.944342,-118.342012 33.944042,-118.359053 33.931562"
```

Trying to do -

```
val polygonCoordinates = boundingPolygon.first().reduce { acc, element ->
                    acc + "${element[0]} ${element[1]}"
                }
```

This is not working.

Comment: Can you explain **what** is not working? Do you get errors? Is the output you're getting wrong? Also a small tip: Whenever you want to do something the functional way with lambdas, do it first with normal loops, then work your way towards the lambdas, by replacing always a small piece of "non-functional" with functional code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `acc` in your reduce operation is of type `List<Double>`, not `String`. Look at the reduce function signature and you should understand why. Here's what I propose to do what you want:

```
coords.first().joinToString(", ") { (x, y) -> "$x $y" }
```

I used destructuring to extract the first and second values from the coordinate lists. So this will only work with 2D coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reducing it, you should just add those into a [`StringBuilder`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-string-builder/), which is efficient when you are doing multiple operations (like concatenating a ton of Strings):

```kotlin
val boundingPolygon = listOf(
    listOf(
        listOf(-125.48845080566404, 47.94508483691371),
        listOf(-124.96110705566404, 42.309040799653665),
        listOf(-117.13884143066404, 45.04173793121063),
        listOf(-118.36931018066404, 48.93624688577435),
        listOf(-125.48845080566404, 47.94508483691371)
    )
)

val sb = StringBuilder()
for (nestedList in boundingPolygon) {
    for (innerNestedList in nestedList) {
        sb.append(innerNestedList.joinToString(" "))
        sb.append(',')
    }
}
if (sb.isNotEmpty()) sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndex)

println(sb)
// Output: -125.48845080566404 47.94508483691371,-124.96110705566404 42.309040799653665,-117.13884143066404 45.04173793121063,-118.36931018066404 48.93624688577435,-125.48845080566404 47.94508483691371

// val stringRepresentation = sb.toString()  // for further use as String data-type
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Reduce, you can use [flatMap](https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-flatmap-example/). It will help you.

```
        List<List<List<Double>>> boundingPolygon = List.of(List.of(List.of(-124.96110705566404, 42.309040799653665)
            , List.of(-117.13884143066404, 45.04173793121063)
            , List.of(118.36931018066404, 48.93624688577435)
    ));
        var l = boundingPolygon.stream().flatMap(lists -> lists.stream().flatMap(doubles -> doubles.stream())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(l);
```

It will print an output as below.

---

```
[-124.96110705566404, 42.309040799653665, -117.13884143066404, 45.04173793121063, 118.36931018066404, 48.93624688577435]
```

Try above code, this will help you.

Comment: He tagged `Java8` as well.